# Hide the circle on UITableView with multiple selection

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have a `UITableView` that hast multiple selection enabled. 
Some of my cells are not to be selected. For those I implement:

in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` 
I set `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;`

and in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`
I call `[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];`.

This works fine. My only caveat is that the little circle left of the cell still appears. It does not get checked when a user taps the cell, but I would like for it not to be shown, when a cell is "unselectable".

How can I hide those circles for certain cells?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the native editing mode of the UITableView to get the circles on your cells?

Comment: yes... all I set to enable it was: `self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;`

Comment: How i can change circle image ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to implement the [`tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:) method in your table view datasource. It will let you prevent the cells you want to be editable and thus the circles not to be shown.

Beware that setting `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` does NOT prevent the cell to be selected. It just removes any visual clue on a selected cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if([[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows] containsObject:indexPath]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Subclassing `UITableViewCell` and adding following method works for me:

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(false, animated: true);
}
```